# Problem observing secondary flow in the Tea Leaf Paradox

Tags: fluid-dynamics, home-experiment

I read about the [Tea Leaf Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tea_leaf_paradox) on Wikipedia, but didn't understand enough, so I wanted to see the secondary flow with an experiment. I set it up and filmed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGAFxs63SlE). It's water and some tea from different tea bags. I stir it for a minute and then see what happens when the stirring stops.

I am not able to see the secondary flow as shown in this figure from the Wikipedia article:

[image: Secondary flow]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What exactly were you expecting to see?

Comment: From the moment i turn off the stirring, I expect to see some tea leaves spiraling downwards close to the glass, and spiraling upwards close to the center. Instead I see everything slowly spiraling down, and tea leaves in the center rotating faster than tea leaves near the edge.

Comment: The motion of objects in a fluid and the motion of the fluid itself aren't necessarily the same. This is especially true if the objects are large, which your tea fragments definitely are, and not neutrally-buoyant, which is also true (you can see that they sink in water). You wouldn't expect a feather to just suspend itself in the air if there's no wind, after all. But you see the primary effect, which is exactly the same one that's shown in the Wikipedia article - the tea ends up piling up in the center.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for something that's neutrally buoyant (and easily available), to maybe see the secondary flow better. I can definitely see the primary effect. I exploit it in beer making.

Comment: Neutral buoyancy will only help you so much - if the particles are too large, their inertia will make their motion very different than the motion of the fluid. You really need a really fine, neutrally-buoyant powder to have much of a chance, probably - industrial solutions for this almost certainly exist.

Comment: Looking more closely at the video, I can see a small gush of movement upwards in the center moments after stopping the stirring (about the 1:04 mark).

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to take a photo from above, then you can see the toroidal vortex as in the first frames in Fig. 1

[image: Figure 1]

In the numerical model, it is possible to determine the velocity field in a liquid and the particle trajectory as in Fig. 2
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Interesting! About how strong is the velocity field of the primary flow compared to the secondary flow?

Comment: It depends on the time. Figure 2 shows a scale of 0.2, and the main stream is 1.